# Script to get Ready, Total and Unacked count from rabbitmq

Tags: shell, rabbitmq

At work we have a number of RabbitMQ queues. A couple of repeating problems which we're trying to resolve usually manifest as the total count for a queue being non-zero and the unacked count being zero. I'd like to find a script of some kind to query RabbitMQ for these numbers for each queue so I can make a reasonable guess if it's in trouble. The one part I'm stuck on is getting the counts. 
FWIW I'm comfortable in perl and most linux scripting languages and can hack others. We have  windows and linux.

Yes we can look at RabbitMQ console but when you've got a lot and other stuff to do, people make mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at [RabbitMQ API](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/). It seems like a good candidate for a correct API call is `GET /api/queues/vhost/name`. An example to get all data for a queue with this API call:

```
curl -s -u user:pass -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XGET http://rabbitmq.host:15672/api/queues/%2F/queue_name | jq .
```

Note that `%2F` is URL encoded character for a virtual host called `/`.

Then you can look at which stats for the queue you want and drill it down using jq. For `messages_unacknowledged` stats, you would use:

```
curl -s -u user:pass -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XGET http://rabbitmq.host:15672/api/queues/%2F/queue_name | jq .messages_unacknowledged
```

To avoid making multiple calls to RabbitMQ, just make a single call and store the result in a variable, then process it with `jq`. You can brush up on `jq` syntax [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).